# SQL Server alias without FROM clause not working - Invalid Column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, alias

Can someone tell me why this simple command won't work in my SQL Server 2012 Express studio?

```
SELECT 
    100 AS Price,
    0.07 AS TaxRate,
    Price * TaxRate AS TaxAmount,
    Price + TaxAmount AS Total;
```

I get an error message:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Invalid column name 'Price'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Invalid column name 'TaxRate'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Invalid column name 'Price'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Invalid column name 'TaxAmount'

Comment: where is your table ??? SELECT 100 AS Price,
0.07 AS TaxRate,
Price * TaxRate AS TaxAmount,
Price + TaxAmount AS Total from TableName;

Comment: I'm specifically trying to call it without a table.  No FROM clause.  Is that possible?

Comment: no its not possible

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll just spell out the formulas instead of reusing alisas

Comment: try to use temp table

Comment: this will be better    SELECT 100 + 100 * 0.07 AS Total;

Comment: Yes, that will work. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What is not possible is to use the alias as a column in the same select stament. To do so you just need to wrap it in a subquery like `select t.Price + t.taxAmount from (SELECT 100 AS Price, 0.07 AS TaxRate, 100*0.07 as TaxAmount) t` but since it is just a mathematical operation `SELECT 100 + 100 * 0.07 AS Total` as pointed out by @Nithin is better.

Comment: Wrap it up in derived tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort of do what you're trying to do by doing either of the following...

```
--option 1...
DECLARE 
    @Price MONEY = 100,
    @TaxRate DECIMAL(9,2) = 0.07;

SELECT 
    Price = @Price,
    TaxRate = @TaxRate,
    TaxAmount = @Price * @TaxRate,
    Total = @Price + (@Price * @TaxRate);

-- option 2...
SELECT 
    ptr.Price,
    ptr.TaxRate,
    ta.TaxAmount,
    t.Total
FROM 
    ( VALUES (CAST(100 AS MONEY), CAST(0.07 AS DECIMAL(9,2))) ) ptr (Price, TaxRate)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (ptr.Price * ptr.TaxRate) ) ta (TaxAmount)
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (ptr.Price + ta.TaxAmount) ) t (Total);
```

HTH,
Jason